# Making "trace" optimise away like "assert"?

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghc

GHC rewrites `assert`s when optimising as just `id`. Or alternatively, it's behaviour can be changed with a compiler flag. However, I noticed the same doesn't happen with `trace`. Is there a version of `trace` which just ends up as `id` if a flag isn't or is set?

More generally speaking, is there a way to alter the behaviour of a function based on the compiler flags used to compile the calling module (not the flags used to compile itself). Much like `assert` does. Or is this GHC magic that can only happen with `assert`?

Comment: I'm always on the fence about answering questions like these. "I don't know of a way" isn't really an answer -- but if nobody's willing to say it, then you just get no response at all...

Comment: GHC does some separate compilation. If the defining module doesn't expose an unfolding, the calling module is stuck with object code.

Comment: Not at my computer right now, but what about putting a call to trace inside assert, and let the entire assert be optimized away?

Comment: If everything fails, there's always the option of using CPP macros. Not very elegant, but at least handling compiler flags is simple.

Answer (score 9):

Warning: I haven't tried this ...

You can replace the `Debug.Trace` module completely with compiler flags. Make another module with trivial implementations of the functions in `Debug.Trace`:

```
module NoTrace (trace) where:

trace :: String -> a -> a
{-# INLINE trace #-}
trace _message = id

...
```

Put this module in another package named `no-trace`.

Hide the `Debug.Trace` module in the arguments to ghc by [including every module](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-thinning-and-renaming) from the base package except `Debug.Trace`. Replace `Debug.Trace` with `NoTrace` from the `no-trace` package.

```
ghc -package="base (Control, Control.Applicative, ..., Data.Word, Foreign, ...)" \
    -package="no-trace (NoTrace as Debug.Trace)" \
    ...
```

---

This came from the crazy idea of using the compiler flag that changes the prelude to replace the prelude with one that had [rewrite rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html) to remove `trace`s, but those rewrite rules would taint anything that imported a module compiled with them, even if a downstream importer still wanted to use traces. When looking up how to replace the prelude I found that ghc can replace any module instead.

Answer (score 6):

No, at least not based on `assert`. The magic for `assert` works the other direction and replaces the identity function with an assertion.

Here's [`assert` from base 4.9](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#assert):

> ```
> -- Assertion function.  This simply ignores its boolean argument.
> -- The compiler may rewrite it to @('assertError' line)@.
>
> -- | If the first argument evaluates to 'True', then the result is the
> -- second argument.  Otherwise an 'AssertionFailed' exception is raised,
> -- containing a 'String' with the source file and line number of the
> -- call to 'assert'.
> --
> -- Assertions can normally be turned on or off with a compiler flag
> -- (for GHC, assertions are normally on unless optimisation is turned on
> -- with @-O@ or the @-fignore-asserts@
> -- option is given).  When assertions are turned off, the first
> -- argument to 'assert' is ignored, and the second argument is
> -- returned as the result.
>
> --      SLPJ: in 5.04 etc 'assert' is in GHC.Prim,
> --      but from Template Haskell onwards it's simply
> --      defined here in Base.lhs
> assert :: Bool -> a -> a
> assert _pred r = r
> ```

Answer (score 5):

OK, back at my computer and finally remembered I wanted to demonstrate this. Here goes:

```
import Control.Exception
import Debug.Trace
import Control.Monad

traceDebug :: String -> a -> a
traceDebug msg = assert (trace msg True)

main :: IO ()
main = replicateM_ 2 $ do
    print $ traceDebug "here1" ()
    print $ traceDebug "here2" ()
    print $ traceDebug "here3" ()
```

When compiled without optimizations, the output is:

```
here1
()
here2
()
here3
()
()
()
()
```

With optimizations:

```
()
()
()
()
()
()
```

So I think this addresses the request, with the standard caveat around `trace` that once the thunk has been evaluated, it won't be evaluated a second time (which is why the messages only happen the first time through the `do`-block).